# What is the difference between "doesn't", "don't" and "not to"?

Tags: grammar, negation

I'm a new English learner, I've found that while expressing negative ideas, sometimes "don't" and "doesn't" are used; but at other times "not to" is used. For example:

> Your question **doesn't** specify exactly.

Can I use the following?

> Your question **not to** specify exactly.

I wonder whenever we should use either of them?

Can somebody explain this grammar?

Comment: Could you please provide some examples of the sentences you find confusing?  "Not to" and "do not" are used in different ways, and it's not clear to me why you would confuse them.

Comment: @Sasan K, the answer that you have accepted makes some incorrect assertions. 1) that **don't** is only used for advising or suggesting. 2) That **doesn't** is only used for describing behaviour and habits. 3) That **not to** is only used about personal resolutions. The real explanations are much simpler: see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write the sentence in the positive, and see whether the verb that you want to negate is the main verb in the sentence. Consider **talk** in these three sentences:

> he talks a lot - *talk is main verb*
>   he really likes to talk - *talk is not the main verb*
>   he likes talking - *talk is not the main verb*

---

**Main verbs**

If you want to negate the main verb and there is already an auxiliary verb (be, have, will, should could, must) in front of it, you insert **not** between the auxiliary and main verbs.

> I am **not** going to the party
>   I have **not** seen him today
>   I will **not** have time tomorrow
>   You must **not** tell anybody about this

If the verb that you want to negate is **be**, just add **not** after it.

> Dinner is ready
>  
>   Dinner is **not** ready

The main verbs **need** and **dare** are special cases: in the positive, it is followed by **to**, and in the negative **to** is replaced by **not**.

> You need to come
>   You need **not** come

For all other main verbs that don't have an auxiliary verb, you add the auxiliary verb **do** and then negate the auxiliary verb. The auxiliary verb has two cases: **does** for third person singular (he/she/it) and **do** for everything else. When negated, this can be written out in full **do not, does not**, or contracted **don't, doesn't**.

> I want to go to the party
>   I **don't** want to go to the party

---

**non-main verbs**

If the verb that you want to negate is not the main verb and it's preceded by **to**, it's an infinitive: you negate it by putting **not** before the **to**

> I told him to come
>   I told him **not** to come

Likewise, if the verb you want to negate is not the main verb and it's got an '-ing' ending, then you negate it by putting **not** before the verb.

> thinking can get you into trouble
>   **not** thinking can get you into trouble

Comment: You've made life a bit complicated there. The verb *BE* is always an auxiliary verb apart from in a few very special constructions. That's *why* you stick *n't/not* either on it or directly after it!! :-)

Comment: @Araucaria, looking at ten randomly selected instances of **is**, only one of them was as an auxiliary verb. The remainder were followed by a noun or an adjective. I think that it's worth mentioning as a special case.

Comment: It doesn't matter - *is* is still an auxiliary there. What's missing is not an auxiliary it's the main verb!!!!!

Comment: @Araucaria: that's probably a more difficult concept to get across than the approach that I have taken...

Comment: I promise you it isn't - I can say that as a teacher. All you need to do is take out the "The main verb BE is special case..."  bit and you're home free. The confusion starts when you say *be* is an auxiliary and then add a special exemption for *BE* for some reason. Anyone who treats *BE* as a main verb when it's followed by a noun or adjective phrase always needs another four or five confusing rules to add on. If you don't, you only need one! :)

Comment: Maybe [see this post for why: "Is 'helper verb' old school?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209132/is-helper-verb-old-school/209189#209189). (The answer is, yes!)

Answer (score 1):

Those have different uses, as it seems to me.

> [***don't***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/don't)
>
> > used as a contraction for do not 
> >     Example: Don't waste your time. 
> >     Notice this is used for advising or suggesting people not to do things
>
> [***doesn't***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doesn't)
>
> > used as a contraction of does not 
> >     Example: He doesn't follow his teacher's instructions. 
> >     Note: This is for describing behaviour and habits.
>
> ***not to***
>
> > This is more used in varied contexts, as in "not to say", "not to be", and so on, probably only while commenting about personal resoultions. 
> >     Example: I promise not to procrastinate. 
> >     If you're getting confused between 'not to' and 'to not', see [this link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/order-of-not-with-infinitive)

Don't and doesn't serve the same purpose but the difference is that doesn't is only used after third person singulars.

So, from the context "Your question doesn't specify exactly" is a more appropriate sounding sentence segment.

The other variant seems wrong as "not to"; makes it more intentional to "have not specified exactly.", and that sounds a bit awkward.

Comment: You said after some specific word we can use not to? like promise!

Comment: Yes, but not always. It's only used in some specific constructs, I've seen it being used with people or pronouns representing people.

Comment: The difference between **don't** and **doesn't** depends only on whether the subject of the sentence is third person (he/she/it).  And whether or not to use **do** has nothing to do with personal resolutions: it's mainly to do with whether or not the verb you want to negate is the main verb in the sentence.

Comment: Yes that's basic, wonder why I didn't add it.